# android environment.directory_pictures not accessible

Tags: android

Android ver 4.3, API 18, Nexus 4

I am trying to save some recorded video files in a specified location. I am using:

```
File mediaStorage = new    File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "DirName");
```

This works fine, but when I try to use the DIRECTORY_PICTURES location instead, as the android developer docs recommend (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media), it doesn't exist.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pictures and DCIM are two separate directory. the first is located at sdcard:/Picture , the second is at sdcard:/DCIM.
I suggest to save your record to sdcard:/Picture/YOURAPPNAME/ (use mkdirs() to create this directory)
and add this to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Remember to call the media scanner after you have saved your file, so it can be displayed on the gallery.
Hope this helps

Comment: that is what I am trying to do, it is not working, though it works for the DCIM folder

Comment: mkdirs() returns false and so does exists() for the new file

Comment: Try to add this to your manifest : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Aha, that fixed it, must have needed permission to create the directory but not the individual files. I actually removed that permission previously when I was trying to work out what was going on. 
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The file exists. But you cannot see in albums if this is not image file. You can see in /sdcard/pictures. Please check it

Comment: the file does not exist, my program checks for it

Comment: it uses mkdirs() and exists(), both return false for the new file

Answer (score -1):

`File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environmet.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);`

And  Declare  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME   in your code...